# Async/Await doesn't work in my example

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, settimeout

Many `JavaScript` developers know about `async/await` and benefits of them so I try to test a old example of asynchronous action, let's see my experiment:

Undoubtedly the answer of below code is:

```
/*Line: 1*/ console.log(`1`);
/*Line: 2*/ console.log(`2`);
/*Line: 3*/ console.log(`3`);

//==>  123
```

So I wanna put a `setTimeout` for second line:

```
/*Line: 1*/ console.log(`1`);
/*Line: 2*/ setTimeout(() => {
               console.log(`2`);
            }, 0);
/*Line: 3*/ console.log(`3`);

//==> 132
```

Because of asynchronous action of second line the `2` is after the `13`, so in the console `132` is showed.

I decide to use `async/await` feature of new `JavaScript` to see `123` again, so I wrote the above code like this:

```
(async () => {
    console.log(`1`);
    await setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`2`);
    }, 0);
    console.log(`3`);
})();
```

But it doesn't work and I saw `132` again in my console. Which part I did wrong or I don't know about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` is not returning a promise. In order to get it to work, you will have to create a function returning a promise that is resolved inside the setTimeout callback.

```js
(async () => {
    console.log(`1`);
    await new Promise(resolve => {
     setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved');
      console.log(`2`);
     },0);
    });
    console.log(`3`);
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

`await` waits for promise to be resolved. Since `setTimeout` is not a promise, execution of program will not wait till it is executed. You would need to wrap `setTimeout()` within promise as specified in first example of following link for your example to work as expected:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Answer (score 1):

You can only await a function which returns a promise. Note that await can only be used inside an async function:

```js
async function someFunc() {
  console.log(`1`);
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`2`);
      resolve();
  }, 0));
  console.log(`3`);
}

someFunc();
```

Answer (score 1):

Await should be called on a function that returns a promise (otherwise it just returns).

`setTimeout` does not return a promise so you should wrap it with a function that returns a promise.

Read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

This code should do the work.

```js
(async() => {
  console.log(`1`);
  await (() => {
    return new Promise( resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(2);
        resolve()
      }, 1000);
    });
  })();
  console.log(`3`);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create function, for example `async function foo() {}`, and make `await` calls inside it.